# Was it a space station?

Tags: star, space, iss

I just looked at the sky and saw a star, not so bright but moving very fast and in almost a minute it disappeared, as it was so fast.
Timing was in between 9.35-9.45 PM in Nuremberg, Germany.
My location is 49.45, 11.06.

So was it International Space station?

Anyway, I'm going to verify it after 92 minutes if i am able see it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heavens-Above](https://heavens-above.com/AllSats.aspx?lat=49.45&lng=11.06&loc=Nuremberg&alt=100&tz=CET) shows two fairly bright objects passing over Nuremberg at that time on 2020-04-14:

- a Resurs-O1 rocket moving south to north
- an Iridium-4 rocket moving north to south

The next visible [ISS passes](https://heavens-above.com/PassSummary.aspx?satid=25544&lat=49.45&lng=11.06&loc=Nuremberg&alt=100&tz=CET) at your location are between April 28 and May 3, all before dawn.